# Python for loop print error

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
for i in range(10):
    x = 0.1*i
    print x
    print x/(1-x*x)
```

I'm trying to print the results out using for loop, but it says `Syntax Error: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'`.

I'm using Python 3.4 and I'm new to Python.

Comment: `print x` is python 2 syntax.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function

Answer (score 1):

The error message is crystal clear, isn't it? Your [`print` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) is missing the parentheses needed for a function call:

```
print(x)
```

Python 2 had a `print` statement where the syntax `print x` was correct; Python 3 has changed this. You should be learning Python from a Python 3 specific resource, for example the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

You syntax for print statement is valid in 2.X but it has changed in 3.X version. You need [parentheses](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html) around your print statement like:

```
print (x/(1-x*x))
```